# Else блок и оптимизаторы

Tags: c++

Есть блок однотипных условий вида. Всего условий около 120.

```
if (event_code == 0xF1)
{
    // action 1
}
else if (event_code == 0xEF)
{
    // action 2
}
...
else if (event_code == 0xDB)
{
    // action 119
}   
else
{
    // print event_code
}
```

Проблема в условии 119 (event_code == 0xDB). Если в коде разместить это условие в самом конце, то оно не выполняется, а вместо него выполняется условие else, которое выводит на печать `event_code = 0xDB`. Все касты и приведения типов в порядке, т.к. если разместить данное условие в начале блока, то оно начинает работать...

Пробовал переделать блок на switch-case и получил такой же результат.
Собирается проект с помощью icc 14.0.2.176 [IA-32].
В доках на icc никаких ограничений не нашел.

Помогите кто чем может)

Comment: Подозрение, что где-то какие-то скобочки не на месте. Так сказать, огласите весь список - покажите весь кусок кода...

Comment: Скорее свего event_code у вас char, а константа 0xDB это unsigned char и поэтому код:   char event_code = 0xDB; std::cout << (event_code == 0xDB); выведет false.

Comment: ...и раз уж подозрение на неверную оптимизацию, то желательно ещё и ассемблерный листинг приложить

Comment: Всем спасибо, проблема в icc.

Answer (score 1):

Покажу несколько способов оптимизации условий.

1. Метод двоичного поиска. Мы выстраиваем дерево таким образом, что бы колличество сравнений было минимальное (обратите внимание что б event_code был unsigned)

   ```
   if (event_code <= 0xEF) { /*Уровень 1*/
     if (event_code == 0xDB) {/*Уровень 2*/
     } 
     if (event_code == 0xEE) {/*Уровень 2*/
     }
   }else  { /*Уровень 1*/    
     if (event_code == 0xEF) {/*Уровень 2*/
       }
     if (event_code == 0xF1)/*Уровень 2*/
     {
       // action 1
     }
   }
   ```

это было дерево {{ EE,EF } , {0xEF, F1 }}
На этом примере не так хорошо видно ефект дерева. Вот пример, как вычислить число бит нужных для числа то 0 до 255

```
     if (a<16){/*1*/
        if (a<4){/*2*/
           if (a<=1)/*3*/ return 1 else return 2;  
        }else{/*2*/ 
           if (a<8)/*3*/ return 3 else return 4;
        }
     }else{/*1*/
        if (a < 64)/*2*/  {
          if (a < 32)/*3*/ return 5; else return 6;
        } else {
           if (a < 128)/*3*/ return 7; else return 8;
         }
```

Тут за три сравнения ясен результат. Три, не 8, не 256. Так можно успешно оптимизировать число сравнений.

2. Метод switch. Многие компиляторы хорошо оптимизируют выражение в switch.  Думаю вы ничего не потеряете если используете switch. Одни компиляторы стоят "дерево" как показано в [1], другие строят таблицу вызовов как в [3]. Но и бывают случаи когда просто лепят сравнения. Проверить что сгенерировал компилятор можно дизассемблером.

   ```
   switch ((unsigned)event_code) {
      case 0xDB:; break;
      case 0xEF:; break; 
      case 0xF1:; break;       
      //...
      }
   ```

   Я часто пользовался switch, и... иногда нужно "выйти" из него не вниз, а вообще. Поэтому кроме break, есть ещё два способа "остановить процесс сравнения" - это `return` и `continue` (если используется цикл).
3. Метод массива вызовов.

   ```
   void handler_1()  {
     }

   void (*my_handlers[])() = { NULL, NULL /*... */, handler_1 };

   void my_proc() {
      if (my_handlers[(unsigned)event_code] != NULL)
          my_handlers[(unsigned)event_code]();     
      }
   ```

   этот метод ефективен если случаев очень много, и они сфокусированы на большом промежутке чисел, например от 0 до 255.

Comment: спасибо, но проблема была в icc, у нас достаточно старая версия, которая периодически капризничает.

Comment: @nick_n_a ,  "Я часто пользовался switch, и...".  Плохо, что вы часто пользуетесь  такими конструкциями, при нынешных возможностях языка

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, а какие есть нынешние возможности языка, упрощающие подобные действия?

Comment: @ goldstar_labs, я могу ответить на ваш вопрос в виде ответа здесь, но другие могут это считать как не ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я на примере ответил на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Ладно, отвечу по своему. Я не считаю правильным использовать такие длинные конструкции `if/else` и  рекомендую по возможности избегать `С` конструкций, поскольку язык `C++` поддерживает такие понятия, как полимофизм, такие типы как  `map`...

"Вот пример, как вычислить число бит нужных для числа то `0` до `255`"
Был такой ответ. А я спрашиваю: сколько вы будете писать `if/else` ов, чтобы вычислить число бит для чисел от `0` до  `1023`, до `2048?`.. 
Вот решение на языке `С++`:

```
const int N = 1024;
unordered_map<int, std::function<int (int)> > number_of_bytes;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
     number_of_bytes [i] = [](int i) {int k = 1; while (i >>= 1) ++k; return k; };
```

Вот, все что нужно. Чтобы менять диапазон, просто нужно задать `N` другое значение, а не вводить новые  `if/else` конструкции. А используется так:

```
int  n = 0;
cin >> n;
cout << " number_of_bytes in the number  " << n << " --- " <<  number_of_bytes[n](n);
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет